# How to insert a string into another string?

Tags: string

I am having a string String `S1="https://www.microsoft.com/s/5f5wpyvu1cbdek2ld3as"`

I am having another string `String S2="0000000/demowidget".`

I want to insert my new string S2 into my old string S1 just before "/s"

any help?

Comment: Good question, would it be suitable for Stack Overflow, you will get a larger audience perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have the following strings.

```
String1 = 'myString/myPattern/someString'
String2 = 'newString'
```

You can append your new string just before the required pattern like this.

```
String newString = 
    String1.substring(0, String1.indexOf('/myPattern')) +
    String2 + 
    String1.substring(String1.indexOf('/myPattern'), String1.length());
```

But make sure your pattern is not repeated in the `String1`, because you might end up replacing just the first occurrence.